# Ruby Hash initialize confusion

Tags: ruby, oop, hash, initialization-list

I have two classes.

```
class Sky
  attr_accessor :args
  def initialize(args)
    @args = args
    puts 'Initializing sky'
  end
end


class ShadowMask
  attr_accessor :sky

  def initialize(args)
    args.each{|k, v| p "#{k}: #{v.to_s}"}
    @sky = args.fetch(:sky, Sky.new({}))
  end
end
```

`ShadowMask` can be created either with a default `Sky`:

```
sm_default = ShadowMask.new({})
# Initializing sky
# => #<ShadowMask:0x007fa215230eb0 @sky=#<Sky:0x007fa215230e60 @args={}>>
sm_default.sky
# => #<Sky:0x007fa215230e60 @args={}>
sm_default.sky.args
# => {}
```

or with a `Sky` that has been previously created:

```
skyobj = Sky.new("Sky Object")
# Initializing sky
# => #<Sky:0x007fa21481a020 @args="Sky Object">
sm = ShadowMask.new(:sky => skyobj)
# "sky: #<Sky:0x007fa21481a020>"
# Initializing sky
# => #<ShadowMask:0x007fa21521ae80 @sky=#<Sky:0x007fa21481a020 @args="Sky Object">>
```

In this second case, the instance of `Sky` already exists, and I do not want to see the output `Initializing sky` from the `Sky` initialization.

The problem with my actual code is that

```
puts 'Initializing sky'
```

is a call to a method that performs several calculations to complete the initialization and set several attributes. And this is repeated without need every time a `ShadowMask` is created.

Interestingly, if I replace

```
@sky = args.fetch(:sky, Sky.new({}))
```

with something like

```
@sky = args.fetch(:sky, 'AnyString')
```

it works fine, but I would loose the possibility of creating a new `Sky` if needed.

I am not sure if the problem is in the syntax or I am making a conceptual mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If all you want is to provide a default `Sky` object when key `:sky` is omitted, then `fetch` is a sub-optimal choice. This will work better:

```
@sky = args[:sky] || Sky.new({})
```

The "problem" with `fetch` is that this will result in a nil `sm.sky`:

```
sm = ShadowMask.new(sky: nil)
```

If this is desired behaviour for you, then use `fetch`. If not, use `||`.

Comment: So with `||` `args[:sky]` is evaluated first and only if it is `false` or `nil` then `Sky.new({})` will be evaluated. Right?

Comment: @Rojj: Yes, this is called "short-circuit evaluation"

Answer (score 4):

I think you need to pass block to `fetch` in order to not see `Initializing sky`:

```
@sky = args.fetch(:sky) {Sky.new({})}
```

the idea behind this is that when you call any method, initially its params (in this case `Sky.new({})`) will be invoked. When you pass block - it will be invoked after inside method `fetch`, not before.

Comment: Yes, method arguments are evaluated before method is called. This means instantiating a `Sky` here.

Comment: So if I understand correctly: `:sky` and `Sky.new({})` are evaluated before fetch is called?